# AnyLogic error message "Invalid width value specified"

Tags: anylogic

I am currently working on my AnyLogic simulation model and I am getting the error message, "Error during model creation: Invalid width value specified 0.000000". How do I get rid of this because I am not able to find any information about this online? Thank you for your time and support!

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Can you add the full details of the output in the console? It should provide you details about what parameter is incorrectly specified. Read here about asking better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you give more details on your model? Which blocks are you using? Which block is throwing error? Generally if you double click on your error message, it will take you to the block which throwing error.

Comment: Hey, this is impossible to solve. Check this guide to learn how to ask good questions here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow